# Error viewing/editing/deleting contributions, error log included

Tags: civicontribute, error

Recently did an upgrade to all parts of our Civi install. Our build is run fully on a local machine (localhost) on an XAMPP stack, now updated to drupal 7 and latest production CivCRM version.

I'm having trouble viewing, editing, or deleting some contributions. It seems new ones that I enter where FinancialType doesn't equal Check are not behaving well. If I try to view, edit, or delete them, I get a yellow box error

One of parameters (value: ) is not of the type Integer

This affects new contributions I enter and ones that are dated prior to the software upgrades. The error log for the most recent occurrence is pasted below. Thanks for any assistance!

```
Apr 25 09:20:21  [info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [message] => One of parameters  (value: ) is not of the type Integer
    [code] => 
)


Apr 25 09:20:21  [info] $backTrace = #0 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(381): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace("backTrace", TRUE)
#1 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Type.php(554): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("One of parameters  (value: ) is not of the type Integer")
#2 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1518): CRM_Utils_Type::validate("", "Integer")
#3 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1396): CRM_Core_DAO::composeQuery("SELECT ft.id, ft.total_amount FROM civicrm_financial_trxn ft INNER JOIN civic...", (Array:2), TRUE)
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/BAO/FinancialTrxn.php(98): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("SELECT ft.id, ft.total_amount FROM civicrm_financial_trxn ft INNER JOIN civic...", (Array:2))
#5 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php(4030): CRM_Core_BAO_FinancialTrxn::getBalanceTrxnAmt("64601")
#6 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/AbstractEditPayment.php(741): CRM_Contribute_BAO_Contribution::getPaymentInfo("64601", NULL, TRUE)
#7 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Form/Contribution.php(248): CRM_Contribute_Form_AbstractEditPayment->assignPaymentInfoBlock()
#8 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(585): CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution->preProcess()
#9 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Display.php(92): CRM_Core_Form->buildForm()
#10 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Display->perform(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution), "display")
#11 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle(Object(CRM_Contribute_Form_Contribution), "display")
#12 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(351): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle("display")
#13 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Page/Tab.php(323): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#14 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/Page/Tab.php(374): CRM_Contribute_Page_Tab->edit()
#15 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(309): CRM_Contribute_Page_Tab->run((Array:4), NULL)
#16 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(84): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#17 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:4))
#18 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/drupal/civicrm.module(445): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:4))
#19 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/includes/menu.inc(527): civicrm_invoke("contact", "view", "contribution")
#20 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/index.php(21): menu_execute_active_handler()
#21 {main}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its because the financial type you used while creating contribution don't have 'Accounts Receivable Account is' and 'Expense Account is' account attached to it.

To check you can navigate to Administer >> CiviContribute >> Financial type.

Besides Financial type click on 'Accounts'

[image]

Check if you can see 'Accounts Receivable Account is' and 'Expense Account is'in the list

[image]

If not then click on 'Assign Account' button and then create a 'Accounts Receivable Account is' and 'Expense Account is' account

[image]

Cheers

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks. The financial types involved in the error only had an 'Income Account Is' designation. I added  an 'Accounts Receivable Account is' entry pointing to 'Accounts Receivable' as you suggested. Also made sure the Payment Method I was employing also designates the 'Accounts Receivable' Financial Account.  I still get the same yellow box error, but the log now registers a slightly different fault: (I'll paste it into a new reply, too long for this comments field)

Comment: Can you post the error?

Comment: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1396): CRM_Core_DAO::composeQuery("\n        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fa.`name`) as financial_account,\n          ft....", (Array:2), TRUE)
#4 /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/drupal/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Contribute/BAO/Contribution.php(4089): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("\n        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(fa.`name`) as financial_account,\n          ft....", (Array:2))

Comment: You also need to configure 'Expense Account is'

Comment: Have updated my answer

Comment: Superb. I made this change to the financial types that were throwing the error, and all are viewable editable deletable as before. Many thanks. And a last question: Is this a configuration I should expect to review after each upgrade cycle, or did it stem  from some prior gremlin in our install?

Comment: not after each upgrade. A financial type should have 4 types as shown in above image by default to function properly.